# How to rapidly prototype an image recognition application using Machine learning & neural network?

Tags: android, python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Known that I'm very new in Machine learning.

> I was thinking about a real world example of using Machine Learning
>   and Neural network in an application and I want to try it with a
>   mobile application who can handle image recognition with the front
>   camera after make an image of something(A cat for exemple).

I really need advice of tools to use to rapidly make a prototype of this application with a python backend that I will call via rest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest if you are new to the machine learning algorithms, that you use an API from [Google](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) or [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api) and get in touch with the flow and how it works .. Once you understand what are the inputs and outputs, you can try to replace the API for you own neural net, try to train it properly and collect results ..

Machine learning is not an easy concept and if you start big, there is a good chance that you'll get discouraged before you finish building it ... The API will provide you with a functional prototype very quickly and thus help you stay motivated to pursue it more ..

But to answer your question more directly, [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) by Google is probably the most sophisticated tool for machine learning in general right now..

There is an excellent course for deep learning with TensorFlow made by Google on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730) ..

Comment: Ok Thanks @koperko.
I will take a look at this.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a link to a perfect free course on TensorFlow ... You should really check it out to learn this stuff more ... Moreover, if you are satisfied with the information here provided, mark one of the answers as accepted so the others know that you already have what you wanted ...

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/pyimagesearch-gurus/). It has lot of stuff related image processiong like face recognition and license Plate Recognition system. It also use  neural networks.

Comment: Yes that is a lot of functionalities I would like to use, but I think it will be a bit complicated to a newbie like me.
Or can you redirect me to a simple tutorial on this website ??

Answer (score 1):

Use an **image recognition API**, like [google vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision).
It is easy and fast to put in an application, and a lot more effective if you do not have experience and ressources in ML

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar for our company website. It is based on caffe though.
You can go through the source code [here](https://github.com/KrishnaKishore123/Segmentation-Demo)

However, it is a segmentation demo. You need to modify it a little.